# Prevent formatting of label text in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, labeling, symbology, formatting

I have a vector layer in *OpenLayers* containing a few point features. Each of my features have an *attribute* `tag` which contains a short text identifying the feature.

*Example:*

> tag: '1e-1'

Applied to my vector layer I have a point style where I specify that I want to display my `tag` as a label above the point:

```js
...
new OpenLayers.Rule(
{
    symbolizer: {
        "Point": {
            label: "${tag}"
        }
    }
})
...
```

**The problem**:
My problem is that my data in this case has some very unfortunate *tags*, since

> '1e-1'

is treated mathematically and displayed on the map as

> '0.1'

**Question**:
Can I avoid the formatting somehow without overriding a bunch of *OpenLayers* objects and methods?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like `label: ${tag} + ""`?

---

**EDIT**

So that does not work. I've been at it all day with no results. I've posted a DEMO so others can play around with to help solve this problem:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rTpgM/)

My only other two suggestions are

1. use something like brackets as a "style" for your labels so instead
   of having a simple `1e-1` value, you have `[1e-1]` or `.: 1e-1 :.` like **[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/rTpgM/1/)**.
2. Use spaces before and after the dash like this `1e - 1`

Comment: I have already tried `label: "" + "${tag}"` and `label: "${tag}" + ""` doesn't work either.

Comment: @Chau : See my update. Sorry. that's all i got (weaksauce). If i think of anything else, i'll re-post.

Comment: Great work! Even though the problem is far from solved, you definitely explored the possibilities at hand! Thanks a lot for your input - I might very well use your *stylish* suggestion :)